# jquery .on('click') only firing once to load social media in div

Tags: jquery

I try to setup some buttons to click and load alternately twitter, pinterest, instagram or facebook in a seperate div.
Only the first click loads the media api. For instance: twitter - pinterest - twitter again - pinterest again. The 'again' ones fails. I did try the same setup with loading text only and it works fine. Known issue?

```
$('#laadTwitter').on('click', function() { $("#smResult").load("twitter.html"); });
$("#laadPinterest").on('click', function() { $("#smResult").load("pinterest.html"); });
$("#laadInstagram").on('click', function() { $("#smResult").load("instagram.html"); });
$("#laadFacebook").on('click', function() { $("#smResult").load("facebook.html"); });
```

```html
<button id="laadTwitter">Twitter</button> 
<button id="laadPinterest">Pinterest</button> 
<button id="laadInstagram">Instagram</button>
<div id="smResult"></div>
```

Comment: Try $(document.body).on('click', '#laadTwitter', function(){  -- delegate  events for document body. Or give more information about what happen after click

Comment: The code should work. Check your network requests tab to verify the load.

Comment: What do you mean by loading the media api?

Comment: You have scripts on those pages, right - they will only trigger on the first load... so don't "throw" away the results, but keep a separate div for each, and set it to display:none or similar instead - should be more efficient too.

Comment: @Mikk3lRo That's a good suggestion, this way all scripts are loading ones and can be viewed seperately several times. (Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/420/) Thanks!